# window.addEventListener("scroll") is not Firing in Nextjs project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In my case I need a some way to detect  scrollY changes dectection. But bellow code is not working at all!

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      console.log("scroll");
    });
  }, []);
```

Why and How can I fix It?

Edit:

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { LangContextProvider } from "../context/language";
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import MultiLang from "../components/MultiLang";
import useScroll from "../components/Scroll";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      console.log("data");
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <LangContextProvider>
      <MultiLang>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </MultiLang>
    </LangContextProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: Can you provide the entire component function?

Comment: Imagine an index.tsx file contain one single method which is useffect

Comment: Sounds like you don't actually have a component set up... please see https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started The code you provided works fine, given it's used in a function **component**.

Comment: please check edit ection